# Subtract data from the same column

Tags: sql-server

I am having difficulties subtracting data from the same column. My data structure looks like this:

```
TimeStamp  ID  state  Gallons
1/01/2012   1    NY     100
1/05/2012   1    NY      90
1/10/2012   1    NY      70
1/15/2012   1    NY      40
```

So I would like to get the result of (100-40) = 60 gallons used for that time period. I tried using the following query:

```
SELECT T1.Gallons, T1.Gallons -T1.Gallons AS 'Gallons used'
FROM Table 1 AS T1 
where Date = '2012-07-01'
ORDER BY Gallons
```

It seems like a simple way of doing this. However, I can not find an efficient way of including the timestamp as a way of retrieving the right values (ex. gallon value on 1/1/2012 - gallon value on 1/30/2012).

ps. The value of "Gallons" will always decrease

Comment: You're missing the other piece of this.  You are not specifying anywhere what other value it is supposed to compare against.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select max(gallons) - min(gallons)
from table1 
group by Date
having Date = '2012-07-01'
```

Comment: Why is the date in the `having`? Why is it July 1st?

Comment: i am getting this error when i run this query 
Column 'dbo.ADS_Device_Data.Device_Data_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Post a question with details @faisal

Answer (score 2):

try

```
select max(gallons) - min(gallons)
from table1 t1
where date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(gallons) - MIN(gallons) AS 'GallonsUsed'
FROM table;
```

would work in this instance, if you are doing a monthly report this could work.  How does the value of gallons never increase? what happens when you run out?

Comment: thanks for you input. You are right, I just mentioned that to exclude the possibility of that event for the sake of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Will you always be comparing the maximum and minimum amount? If not, maybe something like the following will suffice (generic sample)? The first time you'll run the script you'll get an error but you can disregard it.

```
drop table TableName
create table TableName (id int, value int)

insert into TableName values (3, 20)
insert into TableName values (4, 17)
insert into TableName values (5, 16)
insert into TableName values (6, 12)
insert into TableName values (7, 10)

select t1.value - t2.value
from TableName as t1 inner join TableName as t2 
  on t1.id = 5 and t2.id = 6
```

The thing you're asking for is the last line. After we've inner joined the table onto itself, we simply request to match the two lines with certain ids. Or, as in your case, the different dates.